# FullCalendar changes start/end time of event when added to month-view

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

When adding a new event on select, it seems like FullCalendar is changing the start and end time of my event. This only occurs in month-view, not in the agendaWeek-view.

```
mounted () {
  let vm = this
  $(this.$refs.calendar).fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    header: {
      left: 'title',
      center: '',
      right: 'today agendaWeek,month prev,next'
    },
    allDaySlot: false,
    allDayDefault: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
      vm.addEvent(start, end, view)
    }
  })
},
methods: {
  addEvent: function (start, end) {
    // Here this.hour and this.minute are variables which in my example would be 6 and 0
    from = moment(start).set({'hour': this.hour, 'minute': this.minute})
    to = moment(end).set({'hour': this.hour, 'minute': this.minute})
    this.renderEvent(from, to)
  },
  renderEvent: function (start, end) {
    // Make temporary id
    let tmpId = `tmp-${this.getLocalEvtId()}`

    console.log(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))

    // Add new event
    $(this.$refs.calendar).fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
      id: tmpId,
      title: 'NA',
      start: start,
      end: end,
      color: '#bd362f',
      editable: false
    }, false)

    // Find newly created event
    let event = $(this.$refs.calendar).fullCalendar('clientEvents', tmpId)[0]

    console.log(event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
  }
}
```

When I add an event with this code, the first console.log logs 2018-04-10 06:00 (or whatever time I set as start), but the second 2018-04-10 00:00. When adding an event from the agendaWeek-view, both logs 2018-04-10 06:00. Anyone experienced a similar issue?

**EDIT:** JSFiddle [jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/494](http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/494)

Comment: what is "renderEvent" (at the top of your code) in this context? It's not a fullCalendar option. Where and how are "start" and "end" defined in this context? Again it's not clear. Anyway, if you're adding an event via the month view, then it cannot know what time you wanted it to start because the month view doesn't have a time axis, so it will just default to midnight. What do you mean by "whatever time I set as start"...if you used the "select" event to drag in the month view, you don't get to set a time at all. Your whole question is a little unclear, unfortunately. Can you clarify things?

Comment: Sorry if it was a bit unclear, I think my work to show the root of the problem led me to remove a bit too much. I've tried to add a bit more relevant code to clarify. 

Explanation of code: I'm taking the start and end of the selection, which is then sent to the function addEvent. In addEvent, start and end is given new hour and minute, based on some variables set by the user. Thereafter, these two moment objects are sent to renderEvent. Here, the event is added with the correct moment-objects, but for some reason changed afterwards.

Comment: I don't have vueJS, but using the same setup in conventional JS I can't reproduce your issue - see http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/491/ . Doesn't matter which view type you use, the second logged moment is correct with respect to the time. Although since the event will be marked allDay by fullCalendar, it's hard to see what this will achieve.

Comment: Great that you added a fiddle! I actually managed to recreate the issue in your fiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/494/

Comment: What did you change in there?

Comment: Ops, sorry, should have explained. I added "allDayDefault: false" to fullCalendar, and "if (view.name === 'agendaWeek') to.add(1, 'days')" to addEvent

Comment: the second thing is not relevant, since it only applies to week views, but I can see how the first one would be.

Comment: I would guess fullCalendar is checking the view being used, and making an assumption about the time based on whether the user had the ability to select the time, and acting accordingly, disregarding the change you make to it before rendering the event. You'd have to check the source code to see if that's true, but that would be my educated guess based on the behaviour shown.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, thanks for taking a look

Comment: Actually scratch that, I solved it - see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out with the help of this documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment

fullCalendar extends momentJS to make moments be potentially *ambiguously-timed*. When you select an area on a time-less view type such as month, it creates an ambiguously timed moment, and calling momentJS's "set" method on this type of moment to set the time has no effect, or at least fullCalendar takes no account of it (I would guess that it checks to see if the moment "hasTime" before deciding how to render it. Moments created via dragging on the "month" view will have this flag set to `false`, even after you try to set components of the time).

What you need to do is use fullCalendar's extension "time" method to set the time and make fullCalendar consider the moment object to be non-ambiguous (with respect to time) again:

```
function addEvent(start, end, view) {
  start.time('06:00:00');
  end.time('06:30:00');

  if (view.name === 'agendaWeek') to.add(1, 'days')
  renderEvent(start, end);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/495/ for a working example.